# How to convert text file (raw data) data into excel in pandas or python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas, group-by

```
**
```

> How to conver text file data into excel arrange into header and values
> in excel ?

**text.file data
-[ipv9 : 200.1.0.0/10] - 0

```
[GDIP]
Host address            - 200.00.99.22
Host address (decimal)  - 122345560
Host address (hex)      - B00009
Net address         - 19.0.0.8 - 8.0.09.9
Networker            - 2.2.2.2.2

-[ipv7 : 700.9.0.0/90] - 6
 [HYKO]
Hostaddress            - 500.00.00.00
Host address (decimal)  - 987654
Host address (hex)      - D00008
Net address         - 197.0.0.99.00 - 9.9.0.0.9
Networker            - 3.3.3.3.3 - 10.0.8.9
```

**Output Excel data**

```
Host address    Host address (decimal)    Host address (hex)  Net address                   Networker  /remaining 
  
  200.00.99.22     122345560                  B00009                19.0.0.8 - 8.0.09.9     2.2.2.2.2
  
  500.00.00.00      987654                    D00008                197.0.0.99.00 - 9.9.0.0.9    3.3.3.3.3 - 10.0.8.9    / remaining
```

Comment: Can you post your code showing your attempt at solving this problem?

Comment: I am not getting ..

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try. hope it helps!, you can also try it -

```
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text_file_data = f.read()

rows = text_file_data.strip().split('\n\n')

list_data = []

for record in rows:
    lines = record.split('\n')

    dict_data = {}
    for line in lines:
        if '-' in line and 'ipv' not in line:
            key, value = line.split('-', 1)
            dict_data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    list_data.append(dict_data)
print(list_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_data)
df = df[['Host address', 'Host address (decimal)', 'Host address (hex)', 'Net address', 'Networker']]

print(df)
```